# How to get a constructor for a Public class to run

Tags: vb.net, class, dictionary, constructor

I have a Public class with a Public Shared Dictionary in vb.net. The constructor does not seem to be running. I have a breakpoint in the constructor which does not break. Also when I make a database update, the new values do not show up in the dictionary.

```
Public Class SkywalkerPolicy

Public Shared CustomPolicies As Dictionary(Of String, String)

Shared Sub New()
    CustomPolicies = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim bvin As String = String.Empty
    Dim title As String = String.Empty
    Dim poldescr As String = String.Empty
    Dim dtResult As New DataTable("Result")
    dtResult.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    Dim request As New DataRequest

    request.Command = "sky_PolicyDictionary_s"
    request.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    request.Transactional = False
    Dim result As DataSet
    result = SqlDataHelper.ExecuteDataSet(request)

    If Not result Is Nothing Then
        If result.Tables.Count() > 0 Then
            dtResult = result.Tables(0)
            For Each row In dtResult.AsEnumerable
                bvin = row.Item(1)
                title = row.Item(0)
                poldescr = row.Item(2)
                If CustomPolicies.ContainsKey(title) Then
                    CustomPolicies(title) += poldescr
                Else
                    CustomPolicies.Add(title, poldescr)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

When I access the dictionary, any changes I've made to the data do not show up.

```
Dim pol As String = SkywalkerPolicy.CustomPolicies("Orders and Shipping Details")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can get the constructor to work?

Or should I have an additional Sub which duplicates initializing the dictionary before I use it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you instantiating the class as an object somewhere... eg. Private MyPolicy = New SkywalkerPolicy ?

Comment: Then the New method should run

Comment: I just tried that as                                                                 Dim MyPolicy = New SkywalkerPolicy
Dim pol As String = MyPolicy.CustomPolicies("Orders and Shipping Details")                                                                                                           I get Acces of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

Comment: If I add a Public Shared Sub UpdateDictionary() with the same code as the constructor, and then run that sub I am able to get the data updates.

Comment: Well I WOULD say New needs to be Public not shared... but I may be confusing how you intend to use this class. If you are using it as a shared Library, you would need to work this differently. In that case You would not use a New function, but add an InitializeCustomProperties() method that does what New is supposed to do. Then call that at the appropriate point.

Comment: Your ctor 'new' should be an instance method, not shared.

Comment: `New` is the constructor.  It is called when an instance is being created. `Shared` divorces whatever it qualifies from the instance; so a `Shared`/`static` ctor doesn't make much sense

Comment: The shared constructor (`Shared Sub New()`) will be run only once per program run.  It can be thought of as a type initializer rather than an instance initializer; this means that it is executed when the type is first accessed.  You can learn more about this here:  [9.3.2 Shared Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711965(v=vs.71).aspx).  The reference is dated, but completely valid.  There is no reason that a debug breakpoint set in the method should not work.

Answer (score -1):

I have a workaround with an Update routine which I call just before accessing the dictionary. But I am still unclear why I can't step through the constructor. So if anyone can answer the original question, I would appreciate an update. Thank you.

```
Public Class SkywalkerPolicy

Public Shared CustomPolicies As Dictionary(Of String, String)

Shared Sub New()
    CustomPolicies = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim bvin As String = String.Empty
    Dim title As String = String.Empty
    Dim poldescr As String = String.Empty
    Dim dtResult As New DataTable("Result")
    dtResult.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    Dim request As New DataRequest

    request.Command = "sky_PolicyDictionary_s"
    request.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    request.Transactional = False
    Dim result As DataSet
    result = SqlDataHelper.ExecuteDataSet(request)

    If Not result Is Nothing Then
        If result.Tables.Count() > 0 Then
            dtResult = result.Tables(0)
            For Each row In dtResult.AsEnumerable
                bvin = row.Item(1)
                title = row.Item(0)
                poldescr = row.Item(2)
                If CustomPolicies.ContainsKey(title) Then
                    CustomPolicies(title) += poldescr
                Else
                    CustomPolicies.Add(title, poldescr)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Public Shared Sub UpdateDictionary()
    CustomPolicies.Clear()
    Dim bvin As String = String.Empty
    Dim title As String = String.Empty
    Dim poldescr As String = String.Empty
    Dim dtResult As New DataTable("Result")
    dtResult.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    Dim request As New DataRequest

    request.Command = "sky_PolicyDictionary_s"
    request.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    request.Transactional = False
    Dim result As DataSet
    result = SqlDataHelper.ExecuteDataSet(request)

    If Not result Is Nothing Then
        If result.Tables.Count() > 0 Then
            dtResult = result.Tables(0)
            For Each row In dtResult.AsEnumerable
                bvin = row.Item(1)
                title = row.Item(0)
                poldescr = row.Item(2)
                If CustomPolicies.ContainsKey(title) Then
                    CustomPolicies(title) += poldescr
                Else
                    CustomPolicies.Add(title, poldescr)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You need to be more specific about how you expect to use this class Roger. There are actually two different answers here depending on how you want to use it. But we can not read your mind.

Comment: I am using this class to define a dictionary of policies which I can then access to display on the web site. As one of the admins for this web site, I or another admin can update the policy or add new blocks under the policy. I am asking why a breakpoint put into the constuctor never breaks.

Comment: When should the constructor actually run, because it does not seem to run when I log off and log back on or when I close the web site and then run another debugging session from Visual Studio. The new data changes are never picked up. So I came up with a workaround. I am still learning the ins and outs of web programming and thought this would be an interesting problem to post. I did not expect a load of criticism for posting about a process I did not understand. I thought I made it clear that I changed the data and the constructor was not picking up the changes and reloading the dictionary.

Comment: What is meant by the constructor runs once when the program first executes? What program? Is it only when IIS is started or restarted? Should it be every time you start a new debug session? Perhaps you could provide a link as to when and how this class would be instantiated when running debug from visual studio. I am self taught so I probably have a lot of holes in my knowledge.

Comment: OK so you are using that class as a library. So, since you are never actually creating an instance of that object, it will never be constructed using the New function. That is fine. Your workaround to call a routine to do the construction in code is the normal method to initialize library objects.

Comment: Regarding data changes... Unless you explicitly reload the data you will not know it changes with this method.